# Cucumber: In which order the feature tags are followed in a cucumber script?

Tags: webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I am facing an issue where I need to run script with three features. Let's say we have 3 feature files with tag names as `@smoke1`, `@smoke2` and `@smoke3`. And I want these to be executed in that sequence.

Issue is that smoke3 is executing first and rest of them afterwards.

This is my script:

```
@Cucumber.Options(
    glue = { "com.abc", "cucumber.runtime.java.spring.hooks" },
    features = "classpath:",
    format = { "json", "json:target/cucumber.json" },
    tags = "@smoke1, @smoke2, @smoke3"
)
public class ex_Test extends AbstractTest { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**: This only works in older versions of Cucumber.

Cucumber feature files are executed in alphabetical order by path and filename. The execution order is not based on tags.

However, if you specifically specify features, they should be run in the order declared.

For example:

```
@Cucumber.Options(features={"first_smoke.feature", "another_smoke.feature"})
```

Should run `first_smoke` and then `another_smoke` (compared to the default which is to run in the other order.

Comment: Justin I agree with your points regarding tagging. Its following  alphabetical order by path and filename. Now but if i add feature as per ur answer "@Cucumber.Options(features={"first_smoke.feature", "another_smoke.feature"})" its throwing error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: D:\framework\new_qa_automation\Login.feature.

Comment: Also please let us know if we can add multiple tags for a single scenario

Comment: I am not sure why you get an exception. Does the file not exist in that directory?

Comment: This will not run the features in order! Cucumber will still run the feature steps in alphabetic order.

Comment: @Nizzy yes you're right, it does not run the features in the order declared.

Answer (score 0):

Ok we got it ,  We can have multiple tags for a single scenario like this @tag1 @tag2 @tag3.

Comment: nope this will not work either..cucumber will run the feature files name alphabetically. so sad.

Answer (score 0):

You can not define the order in way below.

```
@Cucumber.Options(features={"first_smoke.feature", "another_smoke.feature"})
```

Cucumber determines the only alphabetical order and even only first letter of the word.

Answer (score 0):

You can have how many tags you want in feature file, if you want to trigger feature file more times, it's not working like you will add tag more time or more tags from feature like:

> tags = {"@Reports,@Reports"}

And tests are triggered in alphabetical order, it's checking tags not feature file name.